# Making in-memory workspace or folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm working on eclipse plugin. I would like to make by it virtual folder or whole virtual workspace in Eclipse without having it written in File system. (Ergo every read and write, which would Eclipse try to do with files in folder or workspace, would be processed only in memory of plugin.)

But I can't find any suitable method, how to do it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Perhaps you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve because there is probably a better way.

Comment: I am trying to write plug in into jaspersoft studio, which is based on eclipse. It should can open and save file directly from database, without writing it on hdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `IFolder` you can't. The standard Eclipse workspace code does not support in-memory folders or files.